# React router component render a very wrong state

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Test() {
  const s = useS()
  if (s === 'aa') {
    return null
  }
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route component={MyCpt}></Route>
    </Router>
  )
}

function MyCpt() {
  const s = useS()
  return <h1>{s}</h1>
}

function useS() {
  const [state, setState] = useState('aa')
  useEffect(() => {
    subscribe(setState)
  }, [])
  return state
}

const listeners = []
function subscribe(cb) {
  listeners.push(cb)
}

setTimeout(() => {
  listeners.forEach((cb) => {
    cb('bb')
  })
}, 2000)
```

Here is totally runnable code, simply yet wired. As you can see, `MyCpt` will render the state from `useS` will eventually be `bb` (after 2 seconds). However, it will render `aa` no matter how long you wait. if you comment out `return null` inside the `if (s === 'aa')`, it will render `bb` as expect

What the hack is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use some logs (code below), it will be clear. Look at the `console.log`:

```
1. Test aa 
2. Subscribed 
3. Running listeners 1 
4. Test bb 
5. MyCpt aa 
6. Subscribed
```

Steps 1-2) What happens is first "Test aa" is logged, and subscription happens inside the hook, but due to returning null, the component exits.

Steps 3-4) Afterwards, the listener which was registered (**note so far only one listener is registered, see count 1**) is run, hence the output "Running listeners 1", and again "Test bb" is printed from component `Test`.

Steps 5-6) Now, `MyCpt` is being run, and subscription happens, but the listener is not being called again.

---

Here is code with logs:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Test() {
  const s = useS();
  console.log("Test", s);
  if (s === "aa") {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route component={MyCpt}></Route>
    </Router>
  );
}

function MyCpt() {
  const s = useS();
  console.log("MyCpt", s);

  return <h1>{s}</h1>;
}

function useS() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("aa");
  useEffect(() => {
    subscribe(setState);
  }, []);
  return state;
}

const listeners = [];
function subscribe(cb) {
  console.log("Subscribed");
  listeners.push(cb);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Running listeners", JSON.stringify(listeners.length));
  listeners.forEach((cb) => {
    cb("bb");
  });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: My question is actually abstracted from a real-world complicated project, your answer points out the correct direction